# Как задать сессию на сайт + субдомены

Tags: php, сессия

Сейчас сессия задается следующим образом

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['id']=$id;
```

Сессия работает только на сам домен, на субдомены не реагирует. Как сделать, чтобы и при переходе на любой из субдоменом ([sub.domen.ru](http://sub.domen.ru)) была сессия $_SESSION['id']?

И еще, как сделать, чтобы сессися держалась, к примеру, 30 дней?

```
setcookie(time()+3600*24*30,'/');
```

Должен помочь?
И еще, нужно ли постоянно создавать хеш в сессию, чтобы сверяться с неё в таблице, т.к. сейчас в сессию задается лишь идентификатор. То есть, можно ли изменить сессию и зайти под другим идентификатором?

Comment: Может быть, это поможет:
[клик]
[1] [http://www.askdev.ru/question/1239/Сохранение-сессии-при-переходе-на-субдомен/}

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку.

Answer (score 1):

Должно Вам это помочь. [Хранение сессий в пхп](http://www.itnotes.org.ua/programming/php/session_lifetime_extending_gc_maxlifetime.html). Удачи!

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку.